Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unobtrusive') at HTMLFormElement.eval (eval at a (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js)
Sitecore form in v10.3.1, Getting this error for the submit button(Next,Previous and Submit actions),
VM1314:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unobtrusive')
    at HTMLFormElement.eval (eval at a (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16:157), <anonymous>:4:18)
    at Object.success (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16:1361)
    at c (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:27742)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:28487)
    at l (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:78789)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:81117)

Also tried the below solution as per Sitecore Forms on Submit: Cannot read property 'unobtrusive' of undefined but not working, Getting this error in jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:16:157 unlike the solution provided in the link shows (jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:1), Your help here is much appreciated.
code:
public class FormsProcessor : MvcPipelineProcessor<RenderFormEventArgs>
{
    public override void Process(RenderFormEventArgs args)
    {
        var attributes = args.Attributes["data-ajax-success"] as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(attributes))
        {
            return;
        }
        args.Attributes["data-ajax-success"] = attributes.Replace("$.", "jQuery.");
    }
}

config:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:env="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/"
               xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
<sitecore>
      <pipelines>
          <forms.renderForm>
              <processor type="Project.Foundation.SitecoreExtension.FixJqueryReference, Project.Foundation" resolve="true"
                         patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Pipelines.RenderForm.InitializeAjaxOptions, Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc']"/>
          </forms.renderForm>
      </pipelines>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

